# How to get fields of media_entity?

Tags: 8, media

We have a view that returns a `Media_entity (Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media)` using the following in a `hook_preprocess_view_views` hook. When we try to access the `field_media_type` variable, I get a `NULL`. `field_media_type` is a custom field (taxonomy field) on all the `Media` bundles.

How do we get the fields from a `Media_entity`?

```
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media; 

function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $results = $variables['content']['#view']->result;
  foreach($results as $row){ 
    $media_entity = $row->_entity;
    ksm($media_entity->get('field_media_type'); // returns null.
  }
}
```

I also tried the following:

```
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media; 

function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $results = $variables['content']['#view']->result;
  foreach($results as $row){ 
    $mid = $row->mid;
    $media_entity = Media::load($mid);
    ksm($media_entity); // null
  }
}
```

**content array**
[image: content array]

**iterator contents**
[image: iterator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution I found was to use get the `target_id` and use `Term::load($term_id)->getName()` to get the value we wanted.

```
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media; 
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $results = $variables['content']['#view']->result;
  foreach($results as $row){ 
    $media_entity = Media::load($row->mid);
    $media_target_id = $media_entity->get('field_media_type')->target_id;
    $media_type_name = Term::load($media_target_id)->getName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `$media_entity->label()` and that will give you the name. The reason `$media_entity->get('name')` is not working is because the name is a property of the class and not a field.

One little trick you can use to work out which methods you can use on the object is `get_class_methods(media_entity)`.

Comment: I have updated the question so it is more clear as what we are asking for. When we try to access the `$media_entity`, we want to access fields from the media bundle even custom fields such as `field_media_type`. `$media_entity->label()` returns the name of the media entity, but not the other fields.